# What shape is the pupil of squirrels?

Tags: zoology, eyes

In the animal kingdom there is a [striking variety](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pupil) of pupil shapes, with great variety among relatively close relatives. Cats have vertical slits. Siberian tigers have round pupils. Cuttlefish have a W shape. Goats have what I would call a horizontal bar. Many foxes have vertical slits, many dogs have round ones.

I just started paying attention to it and I was looking at some good pictures of both Japanese and European squirrels. I sometimes feel that I see a round irregularity at the centre, but can never be sure.

[image: Japanese squirrel]
[image: Red squirrel?]
[image: Red squirrel]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a good photo of a squirrel eye showing the pupil being round.

[image]

Source: https://www.treklens.com/gallery/photo390926.htm

Also, these acrylic squirrel eyes for taxidermy show a round pupil.

[image]

Source: https://www.mckenziesp.com/Squirrel-Eyes-Acrylic-C3837.aspx